# IIS 7 password protect folder and files

Tags: iis-7, authorization, iis

I am using IIS 7 and I would like sombody to tell me how to password protect a folder.

And how would you get the username and password dialog to show when someone tries to download a file in that directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, make sure you have the authentication role features installed - basic authentication sounds like what you want.  In server manager, right-click IIS, add role features, and install Basic Authentication (under security) if it's not installed already.

In the IIS manager, select a location, open the "Authentication" module, and configure as desired.  Disabling Anonymous and enabling Basic is probably where you want to be - it'll be using Windows users, and access to the resources will be controlled by the NTFS permissions on those resources.

Comment: Could you explain this a little more, preferably in steps. 

_it'll be using Windows users, and access to the resources will be controlled by the NTFS permissions on those resources._

Comment: @shad The user that it's expecting you to authenticate as is a local (or domain) Windows account.  Whether a user is allowed to view a resource is determined by whether they have permissions to the object on the filesystem permissions.